# JXA: How to get 2 terminal scripts to run in the same window

Tags: terminal, javascript-automation

Why does this open two different windows and run each script in a different window? Is there a way to tell it to use the same window?

```
var Terminal = Application('Terminal');
Terminal.activate();
var window = Terminal.windows[0]
Terminal.doScript('ls',window);
Terminal.doScript('cd Desktop',window);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the second parameter inside a "dictionary" using named parameters. This works:

```
var Terminal = Application('Terminal');
Terminal.activate();
var targetWindow = Terminal.windows[0];
Terminal.doScript('ls', {in: targetWindow});
Terminal.doScript('cd Desktop', {in: targetWindow});
```

Have fun! Michael / Hamburg